# Cannot load in Recharts into React. ERROR: Module NOT FOUND

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm building a React frontend and Django backend (but Django isn't being used here, I'm just in the frontend app) application that uses webpack also. Ever since I've tried to implement Recharts to visualise some data. It's consistently giving me this error: webpack compiled with an error: **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './layout/chart' in frontend\src\components'**

This is my **chart.jsx file**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from 'recharts';

function Chart() {
  const data = [
    { name: 'G1', value: 200 },
    { name: 'G2', value: 400 },
    { name: 'G3', value: 100 },
    { name: 'G4', value: 700 },
    { name: 'G5', value: 900 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Line Chart</h3>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={300}>
        <LineChart data={data} margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="value" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{ r: 8 }} />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chart;
```

**App.js file**:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Header from "./layout/header";
import HomePage from "./layout/homepage";
import Chart from "./layout/chart";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Header />
        <HomePage />
        <Chart />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App

const container = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, container);
```

My **directory structure**:
[image]

In App.js... the header and homepage load in fine. But I cannot seem to get the chart to load and display. It just keeps compiling with errors everytime I do npm run dev. I have Recharts installed, and I can even see it in the package.json.

Here's my **header.js file** for reference, it works completely fine unlike the chart.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-body-tertiary">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#" style={{ fontFamily: 'Code Mono, sans-serif', fontSize: '30px' }}>infoScientia</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div className="navbar-nav">
                    <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Data</a>
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
                    <a className="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default header
```

***Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!***

Comment: What does your Webpack config look like? Taking a guess, I'd say it knows to resolve `.js` files but not `.jsx`